# iPhone slows down entire home network

Tags: iphone, wifi, performance

Ever since the automatic upgrade to iOS 7, an iPhone that connects to my Linksys WRT54GL router running DD-WRT, slows down all other connections, from *any* other device. Download speed is reduced by a factor of 3 to 5, and ping times jump from 33ms to 600 - 800ms. This makes it frustratingly slow to use any web application, and appears to happen when some update is going on on the iPhone. However, the last episode has been going on non-stop for more than 12 hours. At a 1.5Mbps DSL, I have no idea what sort of update could take that long, or if something other than an update is going on.

I only have limited access to the iPhone (it's not mine and the owner got quite annoyed with my requests to use their mobile data plan), but I have full control of the router. Banning it by its MAC isn't exactly a solution. What else can be done? I've read through some [posts on Apple's board](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2398063?start=60&tstart=0) but they didn't offer a clear solution.

Comment: The problem is when you have multiple devices using same network it is going to be as slow as the slowest device (but you know that). So what is the iPhone speed when alone on the network.

Comment: why would the network be ass slow as the slowest device?

Comment: Because the router will have to negotiate the speed this way with all clients so as to be sure that they will all avoid collision with frames of the same **time size**.

Comment: bluetooth runs on 2.4ghz, disable it from unnecessary or all devices to avoid a network interference.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the DD-WRT on your router there is a set up you can use to limit the bandwidth for specific IP or MAC.

Here are the [instructions](http://www.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/print.php/3649346) how to set up the QoS (Quality of Services)

and more [instructions](http://www.informatione.gmxhome.de/DDWRT/Standard/V23final/help/HQos.html) here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the router or the firmware, but if it is only happening when an update occurs on the iPhone, i.e. the iPhone is downloading data, you could possibly limit the bandwidth used by the iPhone on the router?

Comment: How does one limit the bandwidth?

Comment: Well - as I said, I know neither the router nor the firmware, so I don't know how (and I don't know if it is possible).

Comment: ??? I gave an idea how this could be done, assuming that the bandwidth is the limiting factor. So if you think it is not, you have your opinion, and I have mine. If you can say that you can't limit the bandwidth for a single device on a router, so please state so.